# Django datefield and timefield to python datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a Django model with separate Datefield and Timefield for an event. Is there a way to convert it to a python datetime object so I can query for the upcoming events with some precision? Currently I get only the upcoming of the following day.

models.py

```
event_time = models.TimeField()
event_date = models.DateField()
```

Basically, can I filter with a minute, or even split second precition?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted :/

Comment: I have no problem with being downvoted, but I surely did not "show no research effort", I wouldn't be posting to SO. The problem is that I would like to avoid changing the database model, at least for now, and I don't know how to query with these two fields. I can define, inside the Event class, something like: 

 def ev_datetime(self):

        return datetime.datetime.combine(self.event_date,self.start)

but then I cannot do the query  .filter(event__ev_datetime__gt=now). That's my problem basically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a `DateTimeField` instead (see [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield) in the docs). Conversion to a `datetime.datetime` is handled for you by Django automatically.

A `DateField` results in a `datetime.date` and a `datetime.time` object. You can use `replace` to merge these values into an updated `date`:

```
>>> today = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 31, 11, 6, 5, 182371)
>>> time = datetime.time(11, 30)
>>> today.replace(hour=time.hour, minute=time.minute)
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 31, 11, 30, 5, 182371)
```

Note that the resulting `date` has 11.30 as time now. Note also that `today` is not modified, it simply computes a new date and time. As you can see, you now have to do the merging yourself because both values are stored in separate fields. That's why a `DateTimeField` is a much better choice, if you have the ability to modify the model's fields.

Answer (score 6):

You shoud add new field like a merge datetime field. Better for Performance.

```
event_full_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

fix old database. for shell like this script.

```
for obj in YourModel.objects.all():
    obj.event_full_datetime = datetime.datetime( obj.event_date.year,obj.event_date.month, obj.event_date.day, obj.event_time.hour,  obj.event_time.minut,  obj.event_time.second) 
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to store a `NULL` (unknown) time then you can use `datetime.combine` within a computed property:

```py
from datetime  import datetime, time
from django.db import models

class Event( models.Model ):
  event_date = models.DateField()
  event_time = models.TimeField( null = True )

  @property
  def event_datetime( self ):
    """The combined event_date and event_time (or midnight if unset)."""
    return datetime.combine( self.event_date, self.event_time if self.event_time is not None else time.min )
```