# Converting timestamp to unix date python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

Here is how the timestamp looks -

```
2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+00:00
```

I'm looking around to convert this to unix date time.

```
datetime.strptime("2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z").strftime("%s")

ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

throws error for me, probably because of wrong format being used.

PS: my virtualenv is on python 2.7

ideas please ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: I gave that the try - getting - ValueError: time data '2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+%Z'

Comment: Python does not support `.strftime("%s")`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11743262/4663466 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/31096353/4663466

Comment: Yes, the `strptime` does not seem to support the "+hh:mm" style UTC offset. I think you should consider looking into the source of the timestamp string: Where does it come from? Can you make it have some other format? Are you guaranteed this format?

Comment: updated question with error message - this is what I am getting from models.DateTimeField

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime)

Comment: please accept one of the many answers here so future readers know what worked.

Answer (score 2):

For **Python 2.7** use [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow):

```
import arrow    
date_str = "2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+00:00"
unix_time = arrow.get(date_str).timestamp
```

On **PY3** (verified on 3.4), using only standard libs

The date string you show will not be parsed by the standard python datetime library since it has a colon in the timezone (see [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue15873)). The colon can be easily removed since it's always in the same position (or use rfind to find its index starting from the right). Your simplest solution is:

```
import datetime

date_str = "2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+00:00"

date_str_no_colon = date_str[:-3]+date_str[-2:] # remove last colon
dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str_no_colon, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
unix_time = dt_obj.timestamp()
```

Note that **arrow should still work with PY3**, and is a better solution in general- you don't want to get into datetime parsing wars with python. It *will* win.

Comment: throws same error - ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'

Comment: interesting! I'm working on python 3.4, works fine. And you're right, I verified it doesn't work with 2.7..

Comment: This solution relies on newer version of python, however I think it's a step in the right direction. When using `datetime` to parse the timestamp you will have to make a similar workaround for the timezone offset. You could for example use `datetime` to parse the UTC offset  and the rest of the timestamp separately and then combine the results.

Comment: [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow) seems to have the functionality you'll need without having to parse yourself.

Comment: note: `arrow.timestamp` drops fractions of a second (it returns an integer timestamp).

Answer (score 2):

python 2.7 strptime() does not support z directive, either you can use python 3.2+ or some other 3rd party library like dateutil.

Comment: note: `%z` does not understand the colon in the utc offset even in Python 3.2+, see [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using `strptime`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279)

Answer (score 1):

**strptime()** has no support for timezones.
So, you can make the conversion ignoring the timezone in the following way:

```
datetime.strptime("2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141", "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%s")
'1437102111'
```

Or in order to avoid using %s, as suggested below in the commments :

```
from datetime import datetime
(datetime.strptime("2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141", "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S.%f") - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
1437112911.066141
```

Notice this is a working version for Python 2, you can also check solutions for other versions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python/8778548#8778548)

Otherwise, you will have to use other libraries (django.utils or email.utils) that support timezones, or implement the timezone parsing on your own.

**P.S.** :

strptime docs appear to have support for timezone, but in fact it has not been implemented. Try :

```
datetime.strptime("2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S.%f%z").strftime("%s")
```

and you will see that it is not supported. You can also verify it by searching more about strptime()

Comment: Wrong, datetime has support for timezones like `+0530` (without the **:** colon in between) , use the `%z` for that.

Comment: And python does not support the `%s` symbol, that is an artifact of the underlying c's `strftime()` function. And that only works in linux.

Comment: I would not recommend to people to use `.strftime("%s")` http://stackoverflow.com/a/11743262/4663466

Comment: @AnandSKumar Well it kind of supports timezones that way, however `strptime` does not seem to accept `%z`.

Comment: yes it does , like I said without the colon in the middle.

Comment: Example - `datetime.strptime("2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+0000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")` . Try this.

Comment: @AnandSKumar With a `%z` my python gives me: ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z'. Does not seem to work. Try it yourself...

Comment: @skyking what version are you using?

Comment: @AnandSKumar 2.7.3. In python 3.2.3 `%z` it seem to work, but according to the updated question the OP does not seem to use that.

Comment: @skyking yes, i tried it in PYthon 2.x , seems like its not implemented there, it has been implemented in Python 3 though.

Comment: `strftime('%s')` is incorrect for utc input (look at the result) even if your system supports %s

Answer (score 1):

The way to parse the date is not right. You'll either need to parse it by hand, find another library (for example the `dateutil.parser.parse` method that will parse your string directly without supplying format string) that supports that format or make the timestamp in another format. Even with newer versions of python the `%z` directive does not accept TZ offsets in the `+/-HH:MM` format (with colon).

As the source of the timestamp is `django.DateTimeField` maybe [this question can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954498/django-datefield-and-timefield-to-python-datetime)?

For converting to unix timestamp you seem to have to do some work since there does not seem to be a direct method for that:

```
(t - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
```

where `t` is the `datetime` (assuming it's in UTC and there is no `tzinfo`) you want to convert to POSIX timestamp. If the assumption is not correct you need to put `tzinfo` in the zero timestamp you subtract as shown below where the assumption does not hold.

If you want to use `dateutil.parser` the complete solution would be:

```
(dateutil.parser.parse(timestamp) - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0).replace(tzinfo=utc()).total_seconds()
```

Comment: while creating the datetime object, I'm still facing issue - datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")

ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'

Comment: @user2119554 Yes I know that, you have to use one of the three alternatives for parsing the timestamp that I mentioned (directly using `datetime` module won't work). Where do you get the timestamp from?

Comment: its created using models.DateTimeField

Comment: @user2119554 Are you meaning django? Are you sure that the timestamp will be formatted in that way? Maybe `arrow` (mentioned in GG_Python's answer may help you parsing the timestamp anyway?

Comment: yeh django, I gone through through it. looks good, However I am not sure which method would help me out converting to unix date. - t = arrow.get('2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+00:00')

Comment: Also there's a possibility that the `DateTimeField` can convert to `datetime` directly. The documentation it mentions "Normalizes to: A Python datetime.datetime object." whatever that means.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer to use `utcfromtimestamp` instead.

Comment: `dateutil.parser` may return an aware datetime that won't work with the naive `utcfromtimestamp(0)`. You could make the latter aware using `.replace(tzinfo=utc)` where `utc` is a [simple tzinfo subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25421145/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yeah, I had some doubts about that `t` could have wrong timezone. Hovewer replacing it is probably not the right thing to do as it just removes the information and consequently does not result in a `datetime` representing the same instant, I updated it to use `astimezone` instead.

Comment: It is wrong. My previous comment is about the 2nd formula, not the 1st one (where do you see dateutil there?) Revert the 1st formula and use `utcfromtimestamp(0).replace(tzinfo=utc)` or `datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=utc)` in the 2nd one. `astimezone()` usage is incorrect and you don't need it whatever input utc offset is (it is handled automatically in the 2nd case)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Well, yes and no. The method of modifying the first term works as well, but your suggestion is more elegant. In the first snippet theres actually no assumption about `t` (apart from that it's  a `datetime` object) so you cannot actually tell without that whether you should add `tzinfo` to the second term or not. Updated the answer to reflect both these observations.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts:

- to convert `"2015-07-17 06:01:51.066141+00:00"` into a datetime object that represents UTC time, see [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279). Or If you know that the utc offset is always `+0000`:

  ```
  from datetime import datetime

  utc_time = datetime.strptime(time_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00")
  ```
- to convert the UTC time to POSIX timestamp (unix time), see [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279):

  ```
  from datetime import datetime

  timestamp = (utc_time - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
  ```